# AJAX - Make API call based on interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have 2 AJAX functions pointing to different `Node.js` routes. The second AJAX call triggers on a button click. 
Requirement - The second AJAX function needs to receive live data from backend Node app and reload the page every `5 secs` with the new data.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route1",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',                                         
            success: function(res) {
                // Some function
            }
        });   
        $("#myButton").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route2",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) { 
                    //This part needs to be excuted/make API call at each interval 
                    //It gets the updated data from backed and reloads every 5 secs


                    //Below is the logic where I am appending to HTML table
                    //I don't want this part to be appended with new data wrt setTimeout()
                    $.each(res.result1, function(key, value) {
                        console.log("Index",key);
                        console.log("Item",value);                          
                        tableData='<tr><td><a onclick="demoDiv()">'+value+'</a></td><td>'+res.result2[key]+'</td></tr>';
                        $('#table1').append(tableData);                            
                    }); 

                    //No changes need for rest of the code

                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    //ABC
                },
                complete: function() {
                    //ABC
                },
            });  
        });
    });           
</script>
```

What do I make use of `setInterval()`, `setTimeout()` or a different approach altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this. I do not recommend to use setInterval on ajax

```js
const route2 = function() { // or () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route2",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      let tableData = []; 
      $.each(res.result1, function(key, value) {
        tableData.push('<tr><td><a onclick="demoDiv()">' + value + '</a></td><td>' + res.result2[key] + '</td></tr>');
      });
      $('#restab').html(tableData.join("")); // use .html() to not append
      // here you have the rest of the function
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      //ABC
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(route2, 5000)
    }
  });
};
$(function() {
  route2();
})
```

Example of loop

```js
const res = {
  result1: ['127.0.0.1:27018', '127.0.0.1:27019', '127.0.0.1:27020'],
  result2: ['PRIMARY', 'SECONDARY', 'SECONDARY']
}

let tableData = []
$.each(res.result1, function(key, value) {
  tableData.push('<tr><td><a onclick="demoDiv()">' + value + '</a></td><td>' + res.result2[key] + '</td></tr>');
});
$('#restab').html(tableData.join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hostname</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="restab">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well the code is working fine for me, except I have few functions inside my `success` which is appending data to `HTML table`  on each API calls and i don't want that to happen. Is there a way to prevent that i.e. every time an API call is made after 5secs it should not append the new data to table. Rest looks good.

Comment: Also I don't fully understand the ECMA script, I'd want to stick to tradition syntax for Vanilla JS.

Comment: I have few functions inside success which generates chart based on the data fetched from backend. Among them one is handling the HTML table data which I don’t want to alter on each setInterval(). Rest should reflect with new data but not the HTML table append function. Hope this gives a little transparency to what I am expecting.